# Generate binary interface specification from C declaration

Tags: c, gcc, clang, abi

I'm implementing foreign function interface for my toy language. Instead of writing compatible declarations manually, I want to reuse C header files provided by operating systems.

How can I get binary interface (such as types of function parameters, memory layout of a structures, type alignments, optimization hints) for a specific platform from C header files? Is there any way to use Clang or GCC to do that?

Comment: you may google for literature about Application Binary Interface (ABI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-dump` option of the [abi-compliance-checker](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/) tool. It will create the ABI dump of the input header files. Add `-xml` option to produce XML output.

In your case you need the following input XML descriptor (descriptor.xml):

```
 <version>
     1.0 /* any version */
 </version>

 <headers>
     /path1/to/headers
     /path2/to/headers
     ...
 </headers>
```

The command to run the tool:

```
abi-compliance-checker -l ANY_NAME -dump descriptor.xml -headers-only
```

The additional `-headers-only` option in the command is needed if you have not specified any shared libraries in the descriptor (in the `<libs>...</libs>` section of the XML descriptor).